# Почему Ubuntu не ставится с Windows 8?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, администрирование, установка, dual-boot

Всем привет.

Раньше, когда ставил убунту, всегда можно было выбрать, как ее ставить - рядом с виндой или поверх винды. Сейчас же пункт "Поставить рядом" отсутствует, то есть можно только или заменить винду, или самому делать разметку, причем жесткий диск, на котором стоит винда, показывает лишь объем, но не показывает занятое место, то есть при разметке все файлы улетят.

В чем может быть проблема и как решать ее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В том, что винда стоит на одном диске, занимая одним партишеном весь диск целиком, и свободного диска под убунту нет.

**Обновление**

[[@dimka3210](/users/6447/dimka3210)](/users/6447/dimka3210) предполагаю, что она занимает один раздел, но длиной в весь единственный жесткий диск.

**Обновление**

[[@Артур Пантелеев](/users/13192/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2)](/users/13192/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2), раздел - это отдельный диск (его видно в explorer) на физическом диске (hdd). Я предполагаю, что убунта просто не видит для себя возможностей поставиться в параллель с виндой, потому что единственный доступный раздел уже занят виндой. Насчет UEFI - не скажу, теоретически какой-то конфликт возможен, но не очень вероятен. Вроде когда-то поднимал win 8 в параллель с убунтой.

Comment: Так раньше тоже также было, но в мастере убунтовском была возможность установить убунту рядом.

Comment: @Etki, вин типа 4 раздела занимает первичных? В этом проблема?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: @Etki может, я не так понял, но из 250гб свободно 200. Возможно ли, что проблема кроется в  UEFI?

Comment: Обновил ответ